# Has anyone had experience with Air China overnight layover at Shanghai?

Tags: layovers, shanghai, air-china

Layover is over 10 hours and I was wondering if hotel is covered cost-wise? Some websites state Beijing only.

If any input can be given, it would very appreciated. Where do you head after the flight? Do the airlines set up transportation to and from airport to hotel? Or is there a process of booking of free hotel beforehand? I only ask because I have been on a different Chinese airline that set this all up, with free breakfast as well.

Answer (score 2):

Air China does offer a free transit hotel under certain circumstanes, such as both inbound and outbound flights being on Air China, and the ticket being purchased on Air China ticket stock (ie, the e-ticket number starts with 999)

You can find details of this service, along with the complete list of conditions, [on the Air China website.](http://www.airchina.com.cn/vaservice/view/homepage/hotel/hotels.jsp)